# jQuery and generated SVG Polygons - creating loop to give each polygon a unique class?

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, polygon

Basic Javascript/jQuery skills are eluding me, I used a generator to create this svg hex grid http://francescasargent.co.uk/blogosphere/playground/hexagons4.html.  If you check out the source code (too long to copy and paste here!) there are around 112 polygons.  I'm trying to give each polygon a unique class, simply 'pg-' then a number from 1-112, for further work.  But i'm stumped at that already.  As a test, i'm trying to loop through the polygons and change the svg text to the number of each individual polygon (will later change to addClass).  This code causes the number in each svg text item to be '111', instead of looping through and assigning them a different, ascending number.  What am I doing wrong?

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

polygons = $('polygon').length;

for(i=0; i<polygons;i++) {

$('polygon').each(function(i, obj) {
    $('text').text('fap'+[i]);
}); 
}
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not using a unique text, you are selecting all texts and giving the same text. Follow code below to give text to polygons

```
var x = 0;
$('text').each(function () {
    $(this).text("text" + x++)
});
```

To give unique class to each polygon follow the code below

```
var i = 0;
$('polygon').each(function () {
    $(this).addClass('pg-' + i++);
});
```

**Update**

addClass doesn't seem to work for SVG Elements so use .attr instead

```
var i = 0;
$('polygon').each(function () {
    $(this).attr('class', function () {
        return this.className + " pg-" + i++
    });
});
```

**Note:** No need for a loop in loop

Comment: Question - in my source code, will the added class appear in the HTML? so, <polygon class="pg-1" ?

Comment: @user3015175 Yes it will

Comment: Unfortunately, the class isn't changing with the above code, or the code from the answer below: view-source:http://francescasargent.co.uk/blogosphere/playground/hexagons4.html

Comment: @user3015175 I don't see you using the code in the link, copy paste the solution to add class to the polygon in the console and you'll see the elements class attribute changes

Comment: 'var i = 0;
$('polygon').each(function () {
    $(this).addClass('pg-' + i++);
}); ' ?.  Maybe there is some conflict in my upload

Comment: Nvm it updated for me now, and i see that it's not adding class which is very weird, i'll get back to you when i find the problem

Comment: `var i = 0;
    $('polygon').each(function () {
        $(this).attr('class', function () {
            return this.className + " pg-" + i++
        });
    });`  @user3015175 try this, for some reason addClass doesn't work it might be because it's a SVG

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here:

```
for(i=0; i<polygons;i++) {
    $('polygon').each(function(i, obj) {
        $('text').text('fap'+[i]);
    });
```

No need to wrap in a `for`. It will loop and change the text each time until it reached n-1 i.e. 111. The last iteration will give "111" to all polygons in each.

You can simply use each with an index:

```
$('polygon').each(function (index) {
    $(this).text("text" + index)
})
```

Also, note that you should be using `$(this)` inside of `.each` to target the current element and then change its `text`.

Comment: @Anton: thanks. and sorry, i didn't notice you beat me to it. why do i take so much time to type out :(